# Get value of views added programatically

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have RadioButton and Checkboxes that are added programatically inside Fragments under ViewPager. Here's how I added the RadioButton/Checkboxes.

```
public class TeaserExam extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //get all the checked values here
            }
        }
    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {    

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1,questionList.get(position).getId(),
                    questionList.get(position).getQuestion(),questionList.get(position).getQuestionType(),questionList.get(position).getChoices());
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int number, int questionID, String question, int questionType, List<Choices> choices) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();

            ArrayList<Integer> choicesID = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> choicesLabel = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < choices.size(); i++){
                choicesID.add(i,choices.get(i).getId());
                choicesLabel.add(i,choices.get(i).getLabel());
            }

            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, number);
            args.putInt("questionID", questionID);
            args.putInt("questionType", questionType);
            args.putInt("choicesSize", choices.size());
            ParcelableChoices parcelableChoices = new ParcelableChoices(choicesID,choicesLabel);
            args.putParcelable("parcelableChoices", parcelableChoices);

            fragment.setArguments(args);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teaser_exam, container, false);

            int questionID = getArguments().getInt("questionID");
            int questionType = getArguments().getInt("questionType");
            int choicesSize = getArguments().getInt("choicesSize");
            ParcelableChoices parcelableChoices = getArguments().getParcelable("parcelableChoices");

            LinearLayout ll_choices = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ll_choices);

            ArrayList<Integer> choicesIDs = parcelableChoices.getId();
            ArrayList<String> choicesLabels = parcelableChoices.getLabel();

            if (questionType == 2){
                //checkboxes
                for (int i = 0; i < choicesSize; i++){
                    CheckBox myChoices = new CheckBox(getContext());
                    myChoices.setId(choicesIDs.get(i));
                    myChoices.setText(choicesLabels.get(i));
                    myChoices.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    ll_choices.addView(myChoices);
                }
            }else{

                //radio group
                RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getContext());
                rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
                for (int i = 0; i < choicesSize; i++){
                    RadioButton myChoices = new RadioButton(getContext());
                    myChoices.setId(choicesIDs.get(i));
                    myChoices.setText(choicesLabels.get(i));
                    myChoices.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                             LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    rg.addView(myChoices);
                }
                ll_choices.addView(rg);
            }

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is right now I have no idea how to retrieve the checked radiobutton/checkboxes value. I want to get all the checked values when I click on a button which will appear only at the last page.

Since all the views are added to ll_choices, is there any way I can get the id and values of all views added under ll_choices?

Comment: Why aren't you holding onto the widgets in fields when you create them?

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry I really don't get what you mean here

Comment: @imin See the two answers below. They both give a little more detail explaining what CommonsWare means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your variables are local to onCreate inside the fragment.

Make them class fields inside the fragment class, initialize them inside onCreate and then they will be available inside the whole fragment class

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer to your question is to keep a reference to the controls which you add programmatically. You can do this with member field variables rather than local variables.

Since you are adding a **list** of dynamic views, you should learn about `ListView` or `RecyclerView`. These are designed for adding dynamic views. I also suggest that you separate the `RadioButton`s and the `CheckBox`es into two separate fragments. Then the activity decides which fragment to show.